# How to get between days elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, mysql, elasticsearch

I had SQL query to retrieve how many days from now and check for in between days.

**MySQL Query**

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE datediff(now(), table_name.created_at) BETWEEN 31 AND 90`

The query will retrieve data that in between 31 to 90 days old.

How to retrieve the same thing in Elastic Search using Search APIs query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math):

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "_created_at" : {
                "gte" : "now-90d",
                "lt" :  "now-30d"
            }
        }
    }
}
```